# How do I save data into Excel file using condition in Python?

Tags: python

I want to know how to save data using conditions in Python.

I have 1 minutes-interval vessel tracking data(lat, lon and speed so on) on a certain year.

How to extract all rows in every 17:30 PM to 6:30 AM per day and save as each data into excel file

For Example:

```
2017-03-01 17:30 10 20 30

2017-03-01 17:31 11 12 13

2017-03-01 17:32 11 12 13
...

2017-03-02 06:30 10 10 10
```

Until this part save as Excel file.

```
2017-03-03 17:30 10 20 30

2017-03-03 17:31 11 12 13

2017-03-03 17:32 11 12 13
...

2017-03-04 06:30 10 10 10
```

Until this part save as another Excel file.

Comment: Didn't get this part.. `vessel tracking data(lat, lon and speed so on) `

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how you are extracting the data?  What exactly is vessel tracking data is that pulled from an API or a database?  Does the information need to update the excel file in real time or only once a day?

Comment: i mean integrated data include current position information(lat,lon) and speed so on of a certain moving vessel as time passes per 1 minutes

Comment: thank u for ur comment. there is  integrated data include position information(lat,lon) and speed so on of a certain moving vessel as time passes per 1 minutes. this vessel pass away same sea area regularly everyday. in order to calculate averaging time when this vessel pass the some waypoints, i want to divide data into using arrival time and departure time.

Comment: 17:30 means departure time and 06:30 means arrival time. and that data type is normal database thank u~